# weird R data.table bug when by contains get

Tags: r, data.table

`get` function usually works without problems in data.table, but I am not able to understand the reason of this bug.

```
library(data.table)
tb<-data.table(x=c(1,2), y=c(3,4), z=c(5,6), w=c("a","b"))
tb[w != "b", .(x=sum(x)), by=.(y, zz=z)] #OK
   y zz x
1: 3  5 1
tb[, .(x=sum(x)), by=.(y, zz=get("z"))] #OK
   y zz x
1: 3  5 1
2: 4  6 2
tb[w != "b", .(x=sum(x)), by=.(y, zz=get("z"))] #not OK?!
Error in get("z") : object 'z' not found
```

(I use R version 3.3.2 and data.table version 1.9.6.)

Comment: Why do you need that? You can simply do `by = c("y", "z")`. Anyway, you should open an issue on the [official bug tracker](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues). (I can reproduce this with 1.10.0.)

Comment: That's just a minimal example, I need something more complex for a larger table. Filled an issue here https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1985.

Comment: I can't imagine any example where you'd need `get` but can't simply pass a character vector.

Comment: My original by clause contains renames/transforms of values in the data table. There are many workarounds, but it would be nice if this just worked.

Comment: `tb[w != "b"][,.(x=sum(x)), by=.(y, zz=get("z"))]` works, I struggle to understand why on select and transform it doesn't